# What are these notations in class diagrams?

Tags: java, uml

I know basics of UML and java's OO interpretations using class diagrams. But after looking at this class, I felt weird. What are the member variables and what do they represent in the actual language? I guessed the first one which is a boolean type (If I'm right), but what are the other member variables especially those which take some arguments? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: It looks like those are just "values we would expect" each variable to hold used as an example. So power is a boolean, speed is an unsigned integer, maxspeed could be anything probably a float, type and mode are probably enums.

Comment: Thanks, but speed seems to take any postive integer >=0, therefore there is no upper limit for it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This diagram you include is not *strict* uml. From what i can understand it means the following:

1. You have a class called ElectricFan
2. Your class has the following member variables (power, speed, maxSpeed, type, etc). In parenthesis i guess that the author has included the values applicable to each member variable.
3. Also, the author includes the methods that are applicable in this class (i.e. switchOnOff(), changeSpeed(), etc).

An important piece of information that the author doesn't include is the visibility and type of the member variables as well method arguments and return types.

If you are interested in learning more about UML you could start by reading Marting Fowler's UML distilled (http://www.amazon.com/UML-Distilled-Standard-Modeling-Language/dp/0321193687).

Answer (score 2):

The values given in brackets are not arguments, instead they seem like enumerator types.
As far as the speed parameter is concerned it looks like an unsigned int.